# Cannot read property 'props' of null - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically i want to call a function from parent component in child component. That function will change parent component's state.

I have created a handler in parent and passed it as prop to child component. 
Now i want to call it in child component.

Parent:

```
  state = { formstep: '1'}
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
  }
  handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      formstep: '2'
    })
 }

 render () {
    return (
      <Form1 handler = {this.handler} />
    )
 }
```

And in child when I try to call handler function it says

> Cannot read property 'props' of null

Child:

```
handleClick() {
   //Saving Some data from form
   //and calling parent function
   this.props.handler;
}

render () {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Continue</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: bind issue in the child onClick function, search on google will result in numerous duplicates for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In child component you need to bind context properly:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Continue</button>
```

or better to bind in constructor:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
// => <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Continue</button>
```

or call it as a method:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Continue</button>
```

Finally, you need to actually call your callback:

```
handleClick() {
   this.props.handler();
   //     note ------^
}
```

Comment: `<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Continue</button> ` This with `()` worked like a charm. Thanks :)